# How should I structure my Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

My question is not necessarily how to code what I am trying to do, but more how to structure the database to make what I want to do work.

I have something that works now, but I see how this could be "non flat" and could be done way better.

What I want to do is have a user sign up and sign in, and create cards.

He/she will give a nickname the card and firebase generates a unique ID (using childByAutoID) for that card. Under each card you can enter a service (like a chore) and that chore will also get a unique ID (chidlByAutoID). What I want is for you to be able to have a chore..call it cleaning gutters, to be capable to be added to as many cards of the same user or just one of them...as well as be aded by other users. I think it would be better to not add 15 "cleaning gutters" nodes, but instead just if the cleaning gutters doesn't exist create it..if it does just add a child under it that is linked to that user.

The reason I think this is better is because I want to be able to say. Cleaning Gutters for card 1 on user 1 is 15 minutes, but cleaning gutters for card 2 user 1 ...or just another user could be 45 minutes....

So I currently have is a user node, a card node, and a service node.

The card under the card node gets an ID and then a few key values like nickname: ...

the card under the user node is just the ID: true ....so I know that the card is tied to that user

I THINK I have the service wrong ......the service under the service node gets a ID and key values and that ID is put on the card note as ID: true as well as the user....

This is my current set up. It works so far, and by that I mean I can add a service on a card for a user and it only shows up on that card, but like I said...I think adding 2 cleaning gutters is less efficient than having 1 cleaning gutters

Also I imagine if one user types cleaning gutters and another types clean gutters there is nothing I can do about that, because I don't have a definite list of all the chores, but I am ok with that.

```
users
     user uid
        cards
           card ID
                services
                     service ID: true

cards
   card ID
       nickname: "chore card"
   services
       service ID: true

services
   service ID
       serviceName: "cleaning gutters"
```

In my head...I would imagine...under the service ID..it would have the card ID or the user UID? and then under that would be details like time etc

I know people might say that the card should be put underneath the user...but I have been told to keep it separate in case I want to let that card be maintained by 2 users later on

I don't know if it matters but I am using Swift 3

Thank you.

Comment: No answer, but in general be mindful of the terms you use and how people will parse them. In the context of Firebase, a UID is short for a User ID: the unique identifier that Firebase Authentication generates for each usr. So there is no such thing as a card UID, a service UID, since those aren't users. There are card IDs and service IDs all right, but not UIDs (in the Firebase definition of what a UID is). Every time I see "card UID" I have to do a double take to figure out if you somehow want to associate cards with users and your question is already complex enough without that extra step.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when I say card UID or service UID ...I am using .childByAutoID, I apologize for using the wrong terminology. I will edit my question to reflect that

Comment: Aside from that: you're too worried about duplicating data. Storing similar data multiple times is quite common in NoSQL databases. For example: a same-named chore might be quite different between two instances. Then again: they might also be (required to be) exactly the same between all instances. One of these approaches is not by definition better than the other - it all depends on the use-cases of your app. If you keep all data for each card, you're essentially building a variant of a TODO list. If you keep a master list of task types, you're building a... hmm... no idea what that's called.

Comment: The thing created by `childByAutoId()` (or `push()` in our other SDKs and `POST` in the REST API) is called a push ID. But they're not UIDs (since they don't identify users), nor are Firebase Authentication's UID actually push IDs.

Comment: OK, got it, originally I intended to duplicate data as needed, but I was told it might be better to keep similar things together if I ever wanted to analyze my database. Good to know about Push ID vs UID, will be helpful to get my idea across more clearly in the future in need be.

Comment: As you can see from the length of my comments, this is a very broad topic that is hard to capture in a decent length answer. Unless you limit it to a very specific use case, I think this is a bit too broad to answer on Stack Overflow. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) (if you haven't done so) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) for great tips on NoSQL/Firebase data modeling.